# PHP with SSE (Server-Sent Events) shown on thousands of viewers

Tags: php

I plan to use the Server-Sent Events feature under PHP to send updated information to thousands of users (between 2500 and 5000) viewing the same web page URL.

I am looking for an advice of any concerns/flaws/limitations that I should be aware to prevent server crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if you plan it as you say. 
Some tips for the server is put a keep-alive limit (15 seconds without new data, re-open connection) because PHP isn't good for handling polling with long time of live.

What kind of data and how big it is you are planing to transfer ? 
You have to consider it all.

If are too big data, consider sending only an identifier of ocurrence in the event pipe and use XHR to hit an API with this ID after for getting the data, use caching, etc etc ...

And: test it, simulate clients, do traffic monitoring and if you server aren't performing as well, you should take a look at other technologies like WebSockets for doing that.

Comment: I have decided to go for webSockets
Thanks a lot!